# SonarQube cognitive complexity metrics

Tags: sonarqube, complexity-theory

we noticed there is a new rule in SonarQube java plugin about cognitive complexity, "Cognitive Complexity of methods should not be too high", but we didn't understood which metric is used by this rule.
Is there a new metric or an older one, with another name, is re-used ?

thanks

Massimo

Comment: <p>A metric for understandability should not replace a metric for testability. The white paper is informative, but the "sumOfPrimes" method doesn't even return the correct result and utilizes the "goto" keyword. As an effort to convince me of a tool that can evaluate how easy my code is to understand, these examples don't lure me.</p>

Answer (score 10):

This rule relies on the new "Cognitive Complexity" metric - for which you can read the definition in the following PDF: ["Cognitive Complexity - A new way of measuring understandability"](https://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/cognitive-complexity.html).

Note that it differs from the "Cyclomatic Complexity" (the original one that has always been available in SonarQube), which is a way of measuring testability of your code.

Comment: I read the document but i didn't found what is the name/key of the new metric in order to extract new values via API.

Comment: The key is "cognitive_complexity".

Comment: Hi Fabrice, I looked for "cognitive_complexity" metric inside metrics table and also I tried /api/metrics/search but I did not found that metric. We are using SonarQube v. 5.6.6  with SonarJava plugin v. 4.10.0.10260